# Inheritance drawing a truck

Tags: java, swing

I recently made a drawing of a car and tried changing the .fillPolygon to .fillRect but it didnt work to change the car to look like a truck. How would I change my code below to make the drawing of the car into a drawing of a truck?I did this on Eclipse.

**Car.java**

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Car {
    //Coordinates if car is drawn at position 0,0
    private int [] x = {0, 0, 20, 25, 70, 80, 105, 110};
    private int[] y = {35, 15, 15, 0, 0, 15, 15, 35};

    private int [] xCurrent = new int [x.length];
    private  int [] yCurrent = new int [y.length];

    private int xOffset = 0, yOffset =0;
    private Color carColor;

      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Sets up the graphical car with the specified offsets.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public Car(int xOff, int yOff, Color color)
    {
       xOffset = xOff;
       yOffset = yOff;
       carColor = color;

       for (int i=0; i < x.length; i++)
       {
          xCurrent[i] = x[i] + xOffset;
          yCurrent[i] = y[i] + yOffset;
       }
    }

    //
    public int getXOffset() {return xOffset;}
    public int getYOffset() {return yOffset;}

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Draws the car at a particular x and y offset.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public void draw(Graphics page)
    {
       page.setColor(carColor);
       page.fillPolygon(xCurrent, yCurrent, x.length);

       page.setColor(Color.black);
       page.fillOval(13+xOffset, 28+yOffset, 14, 14);  // rear wheel
       page.fillOval(83+xOffset, 28+yOffset, 14, 14);  // front wheel
       page.drawLine(15+xOffset, 18+yOffset, 15+xOffset, 3+yOffset);
    }
 }
```

**CarPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CarPanel extends JPanel {
       private Car car1, car2, car3;
       private final int DELAY =20;
       private int x, y;
       private final int SPEED =2;
       public CarPanel ()
       {
           car1 =new Car(200, 150, Color.BLUE);
           car2 = new Car(50, 50, Color.RED);
           car3 = new Car(0, 220, Color.GREEN);
           x =0;
           y= 220;
           setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,300));

           ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener()
           {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
                {
                    x = car3.getXOffset() + SPEED;
                    y = car3.getYOffset();
                    if (x > getWidth()) x = 0;
                    car3 = new Car(x, y, Color.GREEN);
                    x = car2.getXOffset() + SPEED + 5;
                    if (x > getWidth()) x = 0;
                    y = car2.getYOffset();
                    car2 = new Car(x, y, Color.RED);
                    repaint();
                }
          };

          new Timer(DELAY, taskPerformer).start();

       }

       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
       //  Draws the car.
       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
       public void paint(Graphics page)
       {
          super.paint(page);
          car1.draw(page);
          car2.draw(page);
          car3.draw(page);
       }
}
```

**GUITester.java**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class GUITester {

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
       //  Sets up a frame containing a tabbed pane. The panel on each
       //  tab demonstrates a different layout manager.
       //-----------------------------------------------------------------
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Tester");
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          // add any panel into here
          //ArrayReviews panel = new ArrayReviews();
          //ArrayBetter panel = new ArrayBetter();
          CarPanel panel = new CarPanel();
          //NumericKeypadPanel panel = new NumericKeypadPanel();
          //StarPanel panel = new StarPanel();
          //SnowPanel panel = new SnowPanel();
          //Draw1StarPanel panel = new Draw1StarPanel();
          //Rain panel = new Rain();
          //Cards panel = new Cards();
          //SelectionSortPanel panel = new SelectionSortPanel();
          //PersonPanel panel = new PersonPanel();
          //SinPanel panel = new SinPanel();
          //KochSnowFlake panel = new KochSnowFlake();
          //CalculatorPanelSimple panel = new CalculatorPanelSimple();
          frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
       }
}
```

Comment: *"I recently made a drawing of a car and tried changing the .fillPolygon to .fillRect but it didnt work to change the car to look like a truck"* - How? Maybe provide the truck code

Comment: And it would be much easier to use the Graphics 2D shape API

Answer (score 0):

Yuk!  You are declaring `x[]` `y[]` arrays, and then constructing `xOffset[]` `yOffset[]` arrays to translate you car/truck to different positions.  You can let the GPU do the work for you:

```
void draw(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;  // Every Graphics is actually a Graphics2D.
    translate(xOffset, yOffset);      // Move the graphic origin
    g2d.fillPolygon(x, y, x.length);  // Draw with original coordinates
    translate(-xOffset, yOffset);     // Restore graphic origin, for other drawing
}
```

It doesn't turn your car into a truck, but your code doesn't show your attempt, so it is hard to say where you went wrong.

But, if this simplifies your code, perhaps that will help.

As [@MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) points out, the Shape API might also be useful.

```
static Shape CAR_SHAPE;

static {
    // Initialize CAR_SHAPE
}

void draw(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    translate(xOffset, yOffset); 
    g2d.draw(CAR_SHAPE); 
    translate(-xOffset, yOffset); 
}
```

See [Trail: 2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: While all good advice, that doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I know.  Which is why I said, "_It doesn't turn your car into a truck, but your code doesn't show your attempt, so it is hard to say where you went wrong._"